# Synchronizing 2 windows applications to start at the same time

Tags: windows, process, synchronization, executable

I have 2 different executable files in Windows which I need to execute at the same time.

Which synchronization mechanism we can use for Windows to ensure 2 processes start at almost the same time?
The time for which the process runs in less, so manually running the second application after launching first is not a choice.

Comment: even *bat* file which exec this 2 exe

Comment: Wouldn't a bat file execute it serially?

Comment: you can write in bat - `start app1.exe start app2.exe` - as result both app1.exe and app2.exe start in practic at same time. this is normal solution if you not want write code yourself. can you offcourse and run small app which call `CreateProcessW` but use `start` command in *bat* file easyst solution and enouth

Comment: but of course you need use `start` command. not `app.exe` line on *bat* (this will be wait for `app.exe` terminate) but `start app.exe` line - this will ne no wait

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll get to start two processes at the same time is by executing them *nearly* at the same time:

- Use [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) to create both processes with the `dwCreationFlags` parameter containing the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag.

  > The primary thread of the new process is created in a suspended state, and does not run until the ResumeThread function is called.
- So after both processes have been successfully created, start them immediately one after another with `ResumeThread`

It should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: think if we call `CreateProcess` without `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag and `ResumeThread` - this nothing change in practic